# Como criar uma forma oval com perspectiva com CSS puro?

Tags: css, css3

Olá, estou querendo criar a segunda figura na imagem, a forma oval com perspectiva, ja fiz a forma oval, porém, com perspectiva não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
  #oval {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="oval"></div>
```

Como colocar perspectiva na forma oval como CSS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara inicialmente vc precisa colocar o circulo dentro de um container, e nesse container vc coloca o valor da `perspectiva`, que seria a distancia entre a tela e o olho do usuário no `eixo Z`. Depois no elemento oval vc usa um `transform rotateX()` para ele rotacionar no `plano X` do próprio eixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```css
.box{
  perspective: 400px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: inline-block;
}
#oval {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f00 0%, #000 100%);
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    animation: gira 1s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes gira {
  to {
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="oval"></div>
</div>
```

**Recomendo muito que leia esse excelente artigo:** https://css-tricks.com/how-css-perspective-works/

Comment: Thanks bro, vlw mesmo vou marca a resposta obg.

Comment: @AnotherBrink valeu a força, se marcar ✓eu agradeço, não deixe de dar uma olhada no link, é bem didático com exemplos e tudo para vc trabalhar outras perspectivas :D

Comment: Marquei ja, o link eu ja tinha lido mais não tinha entendio, porque li por cima estou relendo. obg.